# Submit a form with a file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a simple form with 4 input on it.

- 2 text input
- 2 check boxes

My current view model posted to server is like the following:

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public string FirstText { get; set; }
    public string SecondText { get; set; }
    public bool FirstBool { get; set; }
    public bool SecondBool { get; set; }
}
```

This works good. I have now the requirement that when the SecondBool value is true the UI should also upload a file to the server. Then I have modified the view model to add

```
public HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFile { get; set; }
```

and modified the form to having an attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

I would like to use, as I am using bootstrap as the base UI framework the [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin but did not get through on how to post and upload the file at the same time. I know it should be very easy to do it.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the `HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFile` to your post action in your controller. You cannot pass via the model.

**E.g.**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model, HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFile)
{
    //..... Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Any suggestion on the client plugin configuration please?

Comment: There is a good sample here: http://powerdotnetcore.com/asp-net-mvc/asp-net-mvc-simple-ajax-file-upload-using-jquery

Comment: @Lorenzo If you take a look at the link provided by nik0lias (http://powerdotnetcore.com/asp-net-mvc/asp-net-mvc-simple-ajax-file-upload-using-jquery) you will find a great sample to add jQuery file upload to MVC project.

Comment: @nik0lias: Yes I have seen that link before. Unfortunately that link upload the file as soon as the file is selected in the file input. I am getting stuck with uloading when the form is submitted

Comment: The example in that link is triggered by button click, could you post what you have so far? In your view?